# Copying and values in same columns (x number of times)

Tags: excel, macros, vba

Trying to copy paste a range of values in column A, a total of 33 times. This is what I got so far but this code creates a blank row with each pasted set of values. Want to create it without the blank space.

Also, would like to have an additional column that matches each of the pasted set of values with 33 different labels I have lined up in row A.

Would appreciate the help! Thanks.

```
Private Sub Repeat_Command()
Dim i As Integer
Range("A2:A10").Select
Selection.Copy
For i = 1 To 33
    Range("A" & 1 + i * 10).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: That's because you are copying 9 rows, but your offset is 10.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will copy without a space between each copy:

```
Sub KopyKat()
    Dim r As Range, i As Long, n As Long

    Set r = Range("A2:A10")
    For i = 1 To 33
        n = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        r.Copy Cells(n, 1)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Using this technique automatically finds the first available destination cell, so you can change the ***A2:A10*** as your needs change.